# using golangGoogle Cloud Storage Authentication

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

I have a go application running on a server. The application needs access to save image to Google Cloud Storage. From the [Google Cloud Storage authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication?hl=FR#service_accounts) documentation is can see how to create a PKCS12 key.

I am using

```
import(
storage "google.golang.org/api/storage/v1"
)
```

How do you use this key with the golang "storage" client in an application?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func ExampleJWTConfigFromJSON() {
    // Your credentials should be obtained from the Google
    // Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com).
    // Navigate to your project, then see the "Credentials" page
    // under "APIs & Auth".
    // To create a service account client, click "Create new Client ID",
    // select "Service Account", and click "Create Client ID". A JSON
    // key file will then be downloaded to your computer.
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/to/your-project-key.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Initiate an http.Client. The following GET request will be
    // authorized and authenticated on the behalf of
    // your service account.
    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)
    client.Get("...")
}
```

--

```
func JWTConfigFromJSON(jsonKey []byte, scope ...string) (*jwt.Config, error)
{
    var key struct {
        Email      string `json:"client_email"`
        PrivateKey string `json:"private_key"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonKey, &key); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &jwt.Config{
        Email:      key.Email,
        PrivateKey: []byte(key.PrivateKey),
        Scopes:     scope,
        TokenURL:   JWTTokenURL,
    }, nil
}
```

For details :

https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/google/example_test.go
https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/google/google.go

Hope this will help.